# Unable to sign up to Aviation SE – Oops! Something Bad Happened!

Tags: support, sign-up, specific-site

Whenever I try to sign up to Aviation SE using my OpenID which I use on other SE sites, I am correctly transferred to my OpenID provider, and after logging in there and confirming the request, I am transferred back to Aviation SE, but I land at the *Oops! Something Bad Happened!* page.

I tried this a few months ago with the same result, and I have ignored the problem since. When I tried signing up again today, the same problem appeared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give it another shot.

You self-deleted a profile on Aviation before and it looks like something went wrong with that on our end, so when you were signing up now we were turning up a deleted profile and things went downhill from there. I cleaned that up, so you should be all set.

Comment: Can you check if the same happened to others who self deleted their profile, and now can't sign up again?

Comment: @ShadowWizard What others?

Comment: Suppose user Jon Doe self deleted his profile on some site a week ago. Maybe something went wrong with that deletion as well, so if Jon try to sign up again now, he will face same error? Naturally it's rare for users to come back after deleting their account, but still some are doing it. (bottom line, my goal is fixing it before they come here to report)

Comment: Thank you, it works now. I don’t recall the original problem very well, but it was something like the site created a new separate account (with a slightly different OpenID, IIRC), so I tried to fix it by deleting the account and trying again or something. Anyway, it works now, so thanks again. :-)

Comment: Fair enough @Anna, thanks.